# Get and Post Action call in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

How we can identify that a particular URL will call the GET/POST action having same name
one for GET and one for POST:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Edit(){}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(){}
```

Or how we can identify that a particular URL will call GET/POST/PUT/DELETE action method

Comment: That should depend on call method from client specifying GET/POST etc.

Comment: Your pages will generate requests for additional pages using the HTTP verb that you specify implicitly or explicitly. Other pages, or a page edited by an unfriendly user, may use an unexpected verb.

Answer (score 0):

When sending a request, the client specifies if it is a GET request or a POST request.

(It is worth noting that there are other request methods than GET and POST, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) for details.)

A minor point, I don't think your example will compile because both your GET method and your POST method have the same signature. Typically your POST method will have a parameter for the data that is submitted by the client.